# Since django 4.1, templates are cached with DEBUG=True. Is this solution right?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cache

As described in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader), since 4.1 the default behavior for template loading changed drastically.

If I understand it right, until 4.0 it worked like this:

- With DEBUG enabled, the templates are loaded in every request, therefore if you keep making changes and reloading while working on a template, you always see the latest version.
- With DEBUG disabled, the templates are cached when initializing the application, therefore you can only see changes in your templates if you also restart the application.

That way, the template caching was seamlessly enabled in production which is great.

Now [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25788) proposal was included and, if I get it correctly, the template loading method must be specified and it's not anymore tied to DEBUG setting, AND, by default are cached.

We want the original behavior so the frontend developer can see the changes without having to restart the app, and we also want the production deployment to have the caching enabled, so we did this:

```py
develop_loaders = [
    "django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader",
    "django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader",
]
production_loaders = [
    ("django.template.loaders.cached.Loader", [
        "django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader",
        "django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader",
        "path.to.custom.Loader",
    ])
]
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [
            "templates",
        ],
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "maintenance_mode.context_processors.maintenance_mode",
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                "wagtail.contrib.settings.context_processors.settings",
            ],
            "loaders": develop_loaders if DEBUG else production_loaders,
        },
    },
]
```

Which works, but I wonder, **am I getting the situation correctly? Do you think this is a solid solution?**.

Also it took me a while because when I read the changelog for 4.1 I didn't grasp that this change would have this impact (we never specified any loader in settings before) so we expected the default behavior to be respected, which led to looking at gunicorn and docker as the first suspicious culprits, etc... so I thought that this question might be useful for other people in a similar situation.

Comment: any chance you've found a more elegant solution since?

Comment: Nope... still using this in every project since.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the cached loader but with the signal handling of your OS. The cached loader has an `reset` method which is called on `file_changed`, this way you can benefit even when debugging of the cached templates.

Do you use `runserver_plus`? There is an issue for it: https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/issues/1766

I do not experience the issue with normal `runserver` command.

Comment: Thanks Jelmer. We work with gunicorn in development, I think I tried `runserver` when I didn't realize yet what was going on but I don't remember the results. Still, I'll investigate about the signal handling + gunicorn when I have a moment for it.

Comment: Gunicorn does not handle the reloads of the templates as far as I know. Your proposal is the right way since it does not require reloading.

Comment: I am experiencing this issue with runserver - django 4.2.1